# How to parse multi-dimensional json array using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have the following jquery function to parse the json array "projectDetail" , but when i try print the value of ApprovalDesc from the array its showing as undefined, please can i know what is the right syntax ?

```
function show(projectDetail) {
          var  project = projectDetail;
            $.each(project, function (i, tweet) {
                $.each(tweet.ProjectUpdates, function (i, tweet1) {
                $.each(tweet1.ProjectApproval, function (i, tweet2) {
                alert(i + ': ' + tweet2.ApprovalDesc);
               var PStatus = tweet.ApprovalDesc;
            });
        });
        });
       }
```

### json output

```
{ "d" : {
      "ProjectUpdates" : { "ExceptionId" : 0,
          "ProjectApproval" : [ { "ApprovalDesc" : "ABCApproved",
                "CreatedBy" : null,
                "CreatedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/", 
                "ModifiedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
                "ApprovalDesc" : "welcome",
                "SortOrder" : 1
              } ],
          "ProjectStatusGallery" : [ { "CategoryId" : 0,
                "CreatedBy" : null,
                "CreatedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/",              
                "ImageName" : "flower",
                "ImageUrl" : "D://Images",
                "ModifiedBy" : null,
                "ModifiedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/",               
              },
              { "CategoryId" : 0,
                "CreatedBy" : null,
                "CreatedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/",                
                "ImageName" : "flower2",
                "ImageUrl" : "D://Images",
                "ModifiedBy" : null,
                "ModifiedDate" : "/Date(-62135596800000)/"                
              }
            ]
        },
 "__type" : "sample"
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

**welcome** should be quoted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

have you called parseJSON on the json string to put it in an object? Then its easy to access, no loop required.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var json = $.parseJSON(your_json_string);

console.log(json.__type.sample);
console.log(json.d.ProjectUpdates.ProjectStatusGallery.ImageName);
```

Comment: it is a jquery function, sorry i should have written $.parseJSON

Comment: ok. in above json output ProjectStatusGallery is list, this list have more elements. i need to parse in $.each(). i have to take value of ImageName in each loop.how to do that one. any one can help me please. thank you